# JavaScript method is not getting called

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

i have written below script inside html file.

I have attached change event of the text box with firstName.change function and one update function in the class firstNameInputEditor which i have extended after creating instance of class firstNameInputEditor.

Now the problem is when change event is getting called my update function is not getting called.

I want to create different instance of firstNameInputEditor which can have different implementation of update function. And this update function should be called internally from change function.

Kindly help

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            User Resgistration for
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id ="myForm">
            First Name <input type="text" id = "firstName" onchange = "firstName.change(event)"/></br>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var firstNameInputEditor = Class.create({
                initialize: function(id) {
                    this.elementId = id;
                    this.elementId.onchange = this.change;
                },

                update :function(event){
                    console.log('outside update', event);
                },

                change : function(event){
                    this.update(event);
                    console.log('change update', event);
                }
            });

            var firstName = new firstNameInputEditor($('firstName'));

            firstName.update = function(event){
                console.log('new update' + event);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, It seems like you havn't added required library.

Add below script code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

Below is the working code for this-

JS Fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/ce75kdr9/3/

```js
var firstNameInputEditor = Class.create({
 initialize: function(id) {
    this.elementId = id;
    this.elementId.onchange=this.change;
  },

  update :function(event){
},

    change : function(event){   
    this.update(event);
    alert("value changed");
    console.log(event);
}
});

var firstName = new firstNameInputEditor($('firstName'));
firstName.update =function(event){
  console.log('new update' + event);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
<body>
<form id ="myForm">

First Name <input type="text" id = "firstName" onchange = "firstName.change(event)"/></br>

</form>
</body>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response . But still iam not able to see console.log('new update' + event); on the console from the update method .I believe only  console.log(event); is getting called.

Comment: Also i included the prototype.js file earlier.

Comment: ohk.. let me check.. however very first error was not added JQUERY and Prototype library... that is resolved i guess... so let me check about  console.log('new update' + event); too

Comment: Also please note that if i am calling firstName.change('pravin'); manually at the end of script proper update function is getting called. Its only via text box on change method it is not getting called.

Comment: I guess the problem with this keyword. When invoked from the script this is correctly pointing to class which i have created. But when on change event is getting called this is pointing to text box. How can we fix it ???

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer. 
In the initilize function i am storing correct reference and using it to call the update function from the change function

```
<html>
<head><title> User Resgistration form</title></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>

<body>
<form id ="myForm" actiion="\resgistrationFormAction.jsp">

First Name <input type="text" id = "firstNameId" /></br>

</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var firstNameInputEditor = Class.create({
 initialize: function(id) {
    this.elementId = id;
    this.elementId.onchange=this.change;
    that= this;
  },

  update :function(event){
  },

    change : function(event){       
    that.update(event);
    console.log(event);
}
});

var firstName = new firstNameInputEditor($('firstNameId'));
firstName.update =function(event){
  console.log('new update' + event);
}


</script>
</html>
```